# Rspec expect assignment (=) method to be called

Tags: rspec, assignment-operator, stub, expectations

I am writing some test where I would like to assert that some method actually calls the assignment method on an object which I have stubbed.

I have tried doing this:

```
expect(test_object.some_object[:whatever]).to receive(:=).with(some_data) #Does NOT work

test_object.method()
```

This does not appear to work. Is there a way for me to do this?

---

The reason for doing this is that the "some_object" is an open struct object which is a stand-in for an external library which I don't want to invoke when testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "assignment method" in Ruby. When you assign a value to variable in Ruby (e.g. local variable, instance variable, class variable), you aren't calling a method. The variable is a "container" of sorts for an object and there is no way for RSpec to track whether or not an assignment to a variable takes place.

The one exception of sorts to this rule is the case of so-called "setter" methods, as used with `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor`. In this case, you still don't have an assignment method per se, but if you define a method such as:

```
class MyObject
  def my_attribute=(value)
    ...
  end
end
```

or use the equivalent `attr_...` calls, then the following code:

```
MyObject.new.my_attribute = 'foo'
```

will be treated as

```
MyObject.new.my_attribute=('foo')
```

and you can stub or set expectations on the `my_attribute=` method like any other method.

Comment: I was under the impression that both the assignment operator and the other operators like +, - and * all were shorthand for methods. Maybe I have misunderstood. Do you have any good reference for where I can read up on this?

Comment: (To see my point, have a look here: [http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm](http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm))

Comment: While it's true that many operators are turned  into method calls, the assignment operator is an exception, as noted on the reference you provided.

Comment: Well, there I go. Strange that I wasn't seeing that when I was looking over it. Anyways, thanks. I think my best solution is to make a setter and getter method that wraps the external library.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variable assignments can be verified:

```
# checks @whatever
expect(assigns(test_object.some_object[:whatever])).to eq(some_data)
test_object.method()
```